# Just installed wordpress website on nginx, and I can see image locally but not online?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Just trying to learn how to host my own site and installed nginx and wordpress on my raspberry pi. The default page has some images that load on my local network 192.168.0.2, but when I visit the page from the ip, none of the images load.

I used the instructions from this site:

https://tonyteaches.tech/raspberry-pi-wordpress/

Comment: Can you check the network tab on your web tools and see the status of the images not being loaded.

Comment: I can actually click on the broken image, and load it in a new tab, but I can't see it on the page. And this is just a default bird image that is on a default theme.

Comment: interesting, on the network tab, what is the status code of the images?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is just me being a noob I guess.  In the settings of word press I changed the site address to my ip, but not my wordpress url. Once I did that it all works great now.

Comment: Yeh your Wordpress url must match the real url in your case your ip when you have no domain name ... otherwise the links in wordpress will be broken.